# How to test is all subscription unsubscribed in Angular?

Tags: angular, testing, rxjs

Basically, I want to check if there any alive subscriptions after the call of ngOnDestroy. Right now the code collects all subscriptions in the component's property-array and unsubscribes on ngOnDestroy. I could easily forget to add a newly created subscription to this array. Want to write a test that will help me eliminate such a situation.

Comment: You can try https://github.com/cartant/rxjs-tslint-rules#rules https://blog.angularindepth.com/rxjs-avoiding-takeuntil-leaks-fb5182d047ef

Comment: thanks! useful link for my knowledge (: didn't find how to enforce unsubscription

Comment: The blog post link in the comment above is no longer valid. The canonical link for the post is: https://ncjamieson.com/avoiding-takeuntil-leaks/

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if you're trying to test whether the ngOnDestroy method is ending the subscriptions started externally on your public observables, or if you're trying to see if there are any stray internal subscriptions left within the component.

For the former you can write a test like this:

```js
  it('should end subscriptions when the component is destroyed', () => {
    // Setup the spies
    const spy = jasmine.createSpy();
    const noop = () => {};

    // Start the subscriptions
    const streams = [component.streamOne$, component.streamTwo$, component.streamThree$];
    streams.forEach(stream => stream.subscribe(noop, noop, spy));

    // Destroy the component
    component.ngOnDestroy();

    // Verify the spy was called three times (once for each subscription)
    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(streams.length);
  });
```

This would ensure that ngOnDestroy does what it's supposed to do and ends any subscriptions that are started on this component's public observables.

If your concern is the latter, however, then the only way of checking for stray subscriptions is by monkey-patching the Observable in rxjs. [This library does it well](https://github.com/awerlang/observable-profiler) (I'm not affiliated). Writing a test with it would be trivial:

```js
import { setup, track, printSubscribers } from 'observable-profiler';

describe('MyComponent', () => {
  beforeAll(() => {
    setup(Observable);
  });

  it('should not have any stray subscriptions', () => {
    track();

    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MyComponent);
    fixture.detectChanges();
    fixture.destroy()

    const subscriptions = track(false);
    expect(subscriptions).toBeUndefined();
  });
  ...
```

Comment: Thanks, Dmitriy! the second solution looks like what I need. will try it

Answer (score 0):

You can make a simple trick that increase a value in a service in each subscription and decrease it in each unsubscribe then you check **if the value 0 so no subscription alive**

```
mysubscription.subscribe( data => { this.myService.myValue++;})
mysubscription.unsubscribe( data => { this.myService.myValue--;})
```

Comment: same here - it's easy to forget about this value while calling subscribe method